# sqlalchemy group_by gives error: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's my query, simplified a little (some filters removed):

```
q = Foo.query.\
    join(Foo.bar).\
    with_entities(Bar.BAZ, Foo.BAT, ...).\
    group_by(Foo.BAT)
```

This gives me an error:

```
column "Bar.BAZ" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

It seems like there are questions on stackoverflow dealing with this error already, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function), but what they're trying to do is sufficiently dissimilar to what I'm trying to do that I'm having a hard time understanding how their solutions apply and so I think it's alright for me to ask about this error again.

All I want is to group by one of the columns on `Foo`. Previously I was doing this in python, but I'd prefer to do it in postgres because I suspect it's faster.

Comment: But what does it mean to select `Bar.BAZ`? Since you're grouping by `Foo.BAT`, `Bar.BAZ` can have multiple values; how do you intend to combine those different values?

Comment: Many Foos can belong to one Bar. So each Foo has a single unique Bar. Foo.bar stores that relationship. BAZ is a name for Foo's bar, so Foo.bar.BAZ (Bar.BAZ) has only one value. I'm not sure how to express this...

Comment: In that particular case, you would just add `Bar.BAZ` to the `GROUP BY` list.