# Type hinting sqlalchemy query result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy

I can't figure out what kind of object a sqlalchemy query returns.

```
entries = session.query(Foo.id, Foo.date).all()
```

The type of each object in entries seems to be `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result`, but a quick `from sqlalchemy.util._collections import result` in a python interpreter raises an ImportError.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is to type hint this function:

```
def my_super_function(session: Session) -> ???:
    entries = session.query(Foo.id, Foo.date).all()
    return entries
```

What should I put in place of `???`? mypy (in this case) seems to be fine with `List[Tuple[int, str]]` because yes indeed I can access my entries like if they were tuples, but i can also access them with `entry.date`, for example.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I too found it curious that the class couldn't be imported. The answer is pretty long as I've walked you through how I've worked it out, bear with me.

[`Query.all()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L3155-L3161) calls `list()` on the `Query` object itself:

```
def all(self):
    """Return the results represented by this ``Query`` as a list.
    This results in an execution of the underlying query.
    """
    return list(self)
```

... where list will be iterating over the object, so [`Query.__iter__()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L3312-L3317):

```
def __iter__(self):
    context = self._compile_context()
    context.statement.use_labels = True
    if self._autoflush and not self._populate_existing:
        self.session._autoflush()
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
```

... returns the result of [`Query._execute_and_instances()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L3337-L3343) method:

```
def _execute_and_instances(self, querycontext):
    conn = self._get_bind_args(
        querycontext, self._connection_from_session, close_with_result=True
    )

    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
    return loading.instances(querycontext.query, result, querycontext)
```

Which executes the query and returns the result of [`sqlalchemy.loading.instances()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py#L35-L105) function. In that function there is [this line](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py#L71) which applies to non-single-entity queries:

```
keyed_tuple = util.lightweight_named_tuple("result", labels)
```

... and if I stick a `print(keyed_tuple)` in after that line it prints `<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>`, which is the type that you mention above. So whatever that object is, it's coming from the [`sqlalchemy.util._collections.lightweight_named_tuple()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py#L951-L974) function:

```
def lightweight_named_tuple(name, fields):
    hash_ = (name,) + tuple(fields)
    tp_cls = _lw_tuples.get(hash_)
    if tp_cls:
        return tp_cls

    tp_cls = type(
        name,
        (_LW,),
        dict(
            [
                (field, _property_getters[idx])
                for idx, field in enumerate(fields)
                if field is not None
            ]
            + [("__slots__", ())]
        ),
    )

    tp_cls._real_fields = fields
    tp_cls._fields = tuple([f for f in fields if f is not None])

    _lw_tuples[hash_] = tp_cls
    return tp_cls
```

So the key part is [this statement](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py#L957-L968):

```
tp_cls = type(
    name,
    (_LW,),
    dict(
        [
            (field, _property_getters[idx])
            for idx, field in enumerate(fields)
            if field is not None
        ]
        + [("__slots__", ())]
    ),
)
```

... which calls the built in `type()` class which according to the docs:

> With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a
>   dynamic form of the class statement.

And this is why you cannot import the class `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result` - because the class is only constructed at query time. I'd say that the reason for this is that the column names (i.e. the named tuple attributes) aren't known until the query is executed).

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) the signature for `type` is: `type(name, bases, dict)` where:

> The name string is the class name and becomes the `__name__` attribute;
>   the bases tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the `__bases__`
>   attribute; and the dict dictionary is the namespace containing
>   definitions for class body and is copied to a standard dictionary to
>   become the `__dict__` attribute.

As you can see, the `bases` argument passed to `type()` in `lightweight_named_tuple()` is `(_LW,)`. So any of the dynamically created named tuple types inherit from [`sqlalchemy.util._collections._LW`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/201c4a60e4b8af56d9c02a3675d1443ba4171c89/lib/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py#L109-L126), which is a class that you can import:

```
from sqlalchemy.util._collections import _LW

entries = session.query(Foo.id, Foo.date).all()
for entry in entries:
    assert isinstance(entry, _LW)  # True
```

... so I'm not sure whether it's good form to type your function to an internal class with the leading underscore, but `_LW` inherits from `sqlalchemy.util._collections.AbstractKeyedTuple`, which itself inherits from `tuple`. That's why your current typing of `List[Tuple[int, str]]` works, because it *is* a list of tuples. So take your pick, `_LW`, `AbstractKeyedTuple`, `tuple` would all be correct representations of what your function is returning.

Comment: This is why we need [protocols](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/).

Comment: `List[Tuple[int, str]]` may cause problems down the line, if one is then going to use the `_asdict()` method on each of the result's items: `Cannot access member "_asdict" for type "Tuple[str, str]"`

Comment: This is a very good answer, however I want to add as of now _LW and AbstractKeyerTuple are no longer part of `sqlalchemy.util._collections`, might be changed or moved elsewhere

Comment: @Matthias much has been done in sqlalchemy to make it more friendly for typing over the last year or two, so I suppose it’s not surprising to see some changes to the internals. There are going to be a lot of questions that need an update when 2.0 is released, I’ll try to find the time to update this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Just print or log the `type(entries)` to see which type is used. No need to read through the module code.

Without checking it, the return might be the same as typical records you would get with `cursor.fetchall()`. Then, the type is just `tuple` - the Python built-in `tuple`. You do not need even need to import `tuple` to use `tuple` in the typing module.

Writing this without having tested it, yet, the main trick is anyway something else: use `type(my_return_var)` to see the type for the type hint.

Mind that a class with the module path must at first be imported.

Another example of how to use the "trick": type hint for a cursor object, taken from [What is the right type hint for the returned sqlalchemy objects "cursor" and "cursor.fetchall()" records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308705/what-is-the-right-type-hint-for-the-returned-sqlalchemy-objects-cursor-and-cu). When the output of the `type(...)` is `<class 'MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor'>`, then you need

- `from MySQLdb.cursors import Cursor` with `Cursor` as the type hint or
- `from MySQLdb import cursors` with `cursors.Cursor` as the type hint or
- `import MySQLdb` with `MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor` as the type hint.

This "trick" of getting the right type for typing is also at [Type hints for SQLAlchemy engine and session objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118095/type-hints-for-sqlalchemy-engine-and-session-objects).

Comment: The whole point of this Q&A was that the output of `type(...)` resulted in `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result`, which was a dynamically constructed named tuple and something _not_ able to be imported like you suggest with this "trick".

Comment: @SuperShoot I see that I misunderstood the question. This answer does not help since the question already knows the type `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result` by means of the output of `type(...)`. I did not read that in the question as such. Shall I delete the question?