# Type hints for SQLAlchemy engine and session objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy, type-hinting

I'm trying to add type hints to my SQLAlchemy script:

```
connection_string: str = "sqlite:///:memory:"
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
session = Session(bind=engine)
reveal_type(engine)
reveal_type(session)
```

I've ran this script against `mypy` but both types comes back as `Any`. What type should the `engine` and `session` variable be?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs or something similar, btw? Mypy doesn't bake in type hints for sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
connection_string: str = "sqlite:///:memory:"
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
session = Session(bind=engine)
print(type(engine))   # sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine
print(type(session))  # sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session
```

Thus, type hinting is achieved the following way for example:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Engine

def test_func(engine: Engine):
    pass
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're like me who found this question while trying to figure out how to annotate SQLAlchemy stuff then follow this guide. Firstly, these are correct annotations:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

connection_string: str = "sqlite:///:memory:"
engine: Engine = create_engine(connection_string)
session: Session = Session(bind=engine)
```

So easy? Oh, no! This is what mypy says now:

```
main.py:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "sqlalchemy"
main.py:1: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
main.py:2: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "sqlalchemy.engine"
main.py:3: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "sqlalchemy.orm"
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

That's because SQLAlchemy is not statically typed, so to make it work you need to install [stub files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051631/what-is-the-use-of-stub-files-pyi-in-python) (files with extension .pyi). Fortunately, there are solutions. If you're using **SQLAlchemy 1.4+** you can use [official stubs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html#installation), in other cases use [sqlalchemy-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-stubs/) typing annotations published by Dropbox.

Install it via pip (or use any other package manager):

```
pip install 'sqlalchemy[mypy]'
```

To get started, all you need to do is create a `mypy.ini` file with the following contents:

```
[mypy]
plugins = sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin
```

Then run it via `mypy main.py` and see no issues!

---

Take into account that this mypy plugin was developed especially for SQLAlchemy 1.4-2.x versions. According to the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html#mypy-pep-484-support-for-orm-mappings):

> SQLAlchemy version 2.0, when released, will include new constructs
> that will allow for construction of declarative mappings in place
> which will support proper typing directly, without the need for
> plugins.