# What is the use of stub files (.pyi ) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, system

I am trying to understand the lower level implementations of python 3. There is one module named **_posixsubprocess** used by the [subprocess module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8184f0fce3b734413e3d3a282f1425d3cb8507fd/Lib/subprocess.py). I tried to find the location of this module in my system and found that it's a stub file.

Could someone guide me as I have no idea about what are the stub files and how are they implemented at the lower level?

Comment: Maybe you were looking for this? [Modules/_posixsubprocess.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f3751efb5c8b53b37efbbf75d9422c1d11c01646/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c)

Comment: So it is essentially a Cython module that can directly be integrated into python interpreter being a C compiled code, correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: "directly integrated" is maybe not the wording I would choose. When compiled it will become a `.so`/`.pyd` file which can be imported if it's findable on the path. You can "easily" create your own modules in C. I doubt that it's `cython` though. It's more likely that it uses [the standard way of writing C extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html)

Comment: btw: You mention `_posixsubprocess`, which is - in CPython - a `.c` file, But you also mention that you see it as a `.pyi` file. Where exactly did you find that `.pyi` file? Do you have a link to the Python source repository?

Comment: .. nevermind... I found it in the "typeshed". I will update my answer

Comment: I think the answer should be a bit clearer now.

Comment: I was confusing the standard way of writing C extensions for python with `python`. It's cleared now. Also, I found this link which will be quite helpful to understand implementation level details
https://realpython.com/cpython-source-code-guide/#part-1-introduction-to-cpython

Answer (score 102, accepted):

### _posixsubprocess

The file you are referencing is a Python module written in C. It's not a "stub" file. The real implementation can be found in the stdlib at [`Modules/_posixsubprocess.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f3751efb5c8b53b37efbbf75d9422c1d11c01646/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c). You can see how writing a C/C++ extension is written by having a look at [Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html). This should help you understanding the code in `_posixsubprocess.c`.

In order to add type-hints to that file (which is an "Extension Module" as it is written in C), the type hints are added to a "stub" file with the extension `.pyi`.

That file can be found in [the typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/_posixsubprocess.pyi) which is a collection of stub files. The typeshed also contains stubs for third-party modules which is a historical remnant. That is no longer needed since [PEP-561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/) has been adopted.

### Concerning stub/pyi files

Stub files contain type-hinting information of normal Python modules. The full official documentation can be found [in the section about stub-files in PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files).

For example, if you have a Python module `mymodule.py` like this:

```
def myfunction(name):
   return "Hello " + name
```

Then you can add type-hints via a stub-file `mymodule.pyi`. Note that here the ellipsis (`...`) is part of the syntax, so the code-block below really shows the complete file contents:

```
def myfunction(name: str) -> str: ...
```

They look very similar to C header files in that they contain only the function signatures, but their use is purely optional.

You can also add type hints directly in the `.py` module like the following:

```
def myfunction(name: str) -> str:
   return "Hello " + name
```

But there are some cases where you want to keep them separate in stubs:

- You want to keep your code Python 2 compatible and don't like the `# type: ...` comment syntax
- You use function annotations for something else but still want to use type-hints
- You are adding type-hints into an existing code-base and want to keep code-churn in existing files minimal