# What is the meaning of three dots (...) in Python code and where can I see the full body of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code of the `atan` and `tan` functions in the `math` module in Python. Their body consist of three dots (`...`). Many built-in functions also do the same. What is the meaning of that and where can I see the full body instead of three dots?

```py
def tan(__x: _SupportsFloatOrIndex) ->float: ...

def atan(__x: _SupportsFloatOrIndex) ->float: ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are math.py and sys.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857355/where-are-math-py-and-sys-py)

Answer (score 9):

It's the **Ellipsis**, it has many meanings and none at all. Let me explain;

It's an 'empty' *singleton* object with no method and its interpretation is purely up to whatever implements the `__getitem__` function and sees Ellipsis objects there.

- It can be used as a substitute for `pass` or not yet implemented code;

```
def my_function(arg): 
    ...
```

- It is used to denote certain types to a static type checker when using the typing module (for type hints).

```
def partial(func: Callable[..., str], *args) -> Callable[..., str]:
    # code
```

- In slice syntax to represent the full slice in remaining dimensions;

```
import numpy as np
>>>   
>>> array = np.random.rand(2, 2, 2, 2)
>>> print(array[..., 0])

[[[0.03265588 0.85912865]
  [0.45491733 0.3654667 ]]

 [[0.58577745 0.11642329]
  [0.88552571 0.69755581]]]
```

Thank you so much for this question, I learned something new in Python today.

Comment: Is it documented in Python's documentation?

Answer (score 6):

It seems you dug into the `math` library.

Actually, the file you are referencing is a Python module written in C.
In order to add type-hints to that file (which is an "Extension Module" as it is written in C), **the type hints are added to a "stub" file with the extension .pyi.**

Type-hints are added via a stub-file *.pyi.

**Here the ellipsis (...) is part of the syntax, so the code-block below really shows the complete file contents.**

Here is a detailed explanation: [What is the use of stub files (.pyi ) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59051631/)