# Correct Type Annotation for objects generated by the functions from a library

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm writing a function that requires `engine` from `sqlalchemy`.

The engine can be initialised in the following manner

```py
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_str+ "schema_name")
```

I'm type hinting for `engine` as follows

```
from typing import Type
engine: Type[sqlalchemy.create_engine]
```

This doesn't give me any error when using `mypy`. However, I do get a note saying `See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports`. I read through that link but got even more confused.

Question.
Is anything wrong with the type hinting that I have used?

### EDIT

I created a test python file as follows

```
from typing import Type
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
import sqlalchemy  

engine: Engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql://root:password@localhost:3306")
```

However, I'm still getting error

```
test.py:2: error: Skipping analyzing "sqlalchemy.engine": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker
test.py:3: error: Skipping analyzing "sqlalchemy": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker
test.py:3: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the docstring of this function you can read

> Create a new :class:`_engine.Engine` instance.

So the correct type is `Engine`.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine

engine: Engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine()
```

SQLAlchemy is not statically typed, so it will leverage [stub files with .pyi extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051631/what-is-the-use-of-stub-files-pyi-in-python).

Dropbox org maintains [sqlalchemy-stubs](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs).

After installing stubs and adding them to your [`.mypy.ini`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html) config

```
[mypy]
plugins = sqlmypy
```

you should see no errors.

EDIT:
Or, as @snakecharmerb pointed out in the comments, if you're using SQLA 1.4+ you might want to install official mypy stubs with

```
pip install sqlalchemy[mypy]
```

and add them to your mypy config

```
[mypy]
plugins = sqlalchemy.ext.mypy.plugin
```

Comment: For SQLAlchemy 1.4 there is an official [mypy plugin](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html).

Comment: Do I need to create a `.mypy.ini` (in my project folder) file after the installation in the venv?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, so if I install this then do I just need to write `Engine` as type-hint?

Comment: You need to create a setup.cfg file as described in the plugin docs (a .mypy.ini seems to work just as well, but I'm not enough of a mypy user to understand the difference

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html > By default it uses the file mypy.ini with a fallback to .mypy.ini, then pyproject.toml, then setup.cfg

Comment: Note that the mypy plugin is specifically for 1.4.x - v2.0 will feature a different approach (though 14-style will still work).