# mypy showing error "Untyped decorator makes function untyped" when using diskcache.Cache.memoize decorator on a typed function

Tags: python, mypy, typing, diskcache

I have a function that returns a list of dictionaries I want to cache using [`diskcache.Cache.memoize`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/api.html#diskcache.Cache.memoize). However, when I run mypy type checks I get an `Untyped decorator makes function "get_local_network_connections" untyped` error.
I'm not sure how to provide the typing hints to keep mypy happy.
Here is an abbreviated version of my code:

```
import datetime
import pathlib
from diskcache import Cache

DEFAULT_CACHE_DIR = pathlib.Path.home() / ".cache" / "hub-cli"
cache = Cache(DEFAULT_CACHE_DIR)

@cache.memoize(typing=True, expire=datetime.timedelta(minutes=10).total_seconds())
def get_local_network_connections() -> list[dict[str, str]]:
    ....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate (mentions the use of stub files to provide type hints separately from the module definition): https://stackoverflow.com/q/59051631/1126841.

Answer (score 0):

I often solve such problems by providing a properly typed wrapper for the underlying untyped decorator. In your example this could look something like:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
from diskcache import Cache
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

# Hide the original decorator
_cache = Cache(Path.home() / ".cache" / "hub-cli")

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


# Create a typed decorator wrapper
def cached(f: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    # Forward decorating to the underlying decorator. This may require
    # a type ignore tag to satisfy mypy, but since this is the only point
    # where we have to suppress types that should be fine.
    return _cache.memoize(...)(f)  # type: ignore

# Now use the typed decorator
@cached
def some_func(x: SomeInput) -> SomeOutput:
    ...
```

Now mypy understands usages of `some_func` again, i.e., it can detect wrong calls, and understands its return type, as if there was no decorator.

If the underlying untyped decorator actually messes with the input/output types, it may be possible to adapt the wrapper accordingly, see [PEP 612](https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/) for details on `ParamSpec` usage.

Wrapping the decorator can have the benefit that commonly passed arguments can be moved into the wrapper. If usages use different parametrizations though, this have to be re-implemented as arguments in the wrapper.