# What is the right type hint for the returned sqlalchemy objects "cursor" and "cursor.fetchall()" records?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-hinting, database-cursor

In search for the right type hint for a sqlalchemy cursor of a sqlalchemy query, here is an example function:

```
import sqlalchemy
from typing import Tuple, tuple

def get_cursor_and_records(
    connection, query) -> Tuple[sqlalchemy.engine.cursor?, tuple]:
    """Make a database cursor for the query and fetch the query output
    :param connection: mysqldb connection to db
    :param query: mysql query string
    returns:
     cursor: row-wise data fetch from the db connection's query
     records: List(Tuple([column types...])) output from cursor.fetchall()
    """
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    return cursor, records
```

The cursor is built with sqlalchemy (in many steps, not just in one step like here):

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(**settings), 
    encoding="utf8"
    ).raw_connection().cursor()
```

The records are then:

```
cursor.fetchall()`
```

From [Type hinting sqlalchemy query result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55371169/11154841), it seems to be right to use `tuple` (as one of three objects to choose from).
[This](https://pysql.tecladocode.com/section06/lectures/16_adding_type_hinting/#adding-type-hinting-to-our-code) shows that `-> List[Tuple[int, str, str]]` would be right for example. Yet, I use this function for many queries with changing column number and types. Therefore I use `tuple`, not fully sure about it, though.

What is the right type hint for a sqlalchemy cursor? And if wrong, what is the right type hint for the sqlalchemy records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by printing out the type:

```py
logger.log_text(str(type(cursor)))
logger.log_text(str(type(records)))
```

Out:

```sh
<class 'MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

Thus, not the sqlalchemy cursor, but the MySQLdb cursor type is used here.
And: the built-in `tuple` is needed, I had mistakenly thought it would be a `tuple` type from `sqlalchemy`.

```py
import sqlalchemy
from MySQLdb.cursors import Cursor
from typing import Tuple

def get_cursor_and_records(
    connection, query) -> Tuple[Cursor, tuple]:
    """Make a database cursor for the query and fetch the query output
    :param connection: mysqldb connection to db
    :param query: mysql query string
    returns:
     cursor: row-wise data fetch from the db connection's query
     records: List(Tuple([column types...])) output from cursor.fetchall()
    """
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    return cursor, records
```

UPDATE: This "trick" of getting the right type for typing is also at [Type hints for SQLAlchemy engine and session objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118095/type-hints-for-sqlalchemy-engine-and-session-objects).

Answer (score -1):

Try this to return tuple of records:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
records = (cursor.execute(query)).all()
return records
```

Comment: Hi thanks and welcome, I look for the right type hint. It is not about code changes, the code works fine and should not be changed.